# Txt project file writing problems C#

Tags: c#, text-files, streamwriter

I don't understand why I can read but cannot write to the file that is inside the project. When i selected release it appeared to write to the file, but on debugging mode it doesn't. When i use same function to write list into the file's lines to a different folder it worked always but not on the file that i want.

Example:
Function:

```
public void WriteLinesFromListToTextFile(List<string> listOfContent, string txtFileName)
{
    StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(txtFileName);
    foreach (string Item in listOfContent)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(Item);
    }
    writer.Flush();
    writer.Close();
}
```

and later

```
List<string> exampleList = new List<string>();
tmp.Add("line1");
tmp.Add("line2");
tmp.Add("line3");
WriteLinesFromListToTextFile(exampleList, "TextOnProjectRoot.txt")
```

In the file properties I selected "Copy Always" and also tried "Copy If Newer".
I ran VS as admin as well.
When I created the file it did copy it to the root folder but just didn't write to it.
I also want to state that there is no exception at all.
Thanks for any help

Comment: It's a little unclear what folder you try to write to. Normally, your project structure would be something like <solutionfolder>\<projectfolder>\bin\  Is it the <projectfolder> you try to write to, or to the bin folder?

Comment: @alex, `File.AppendText( )` creates a streamwriter for the given filename, ready to append text instead of overwriting the file etc.

Comment: Does this produce an error?

Comment: txtFileName is the name of the file. When you are in the solution explorer and add a text item and give it a name you dont have to specify its full path, only the filename. it works when i read from the file just can't write (append) to it.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I do not get any errors. program continues but nothing is written.

Comment: but when your app is running, you will write against the file in your bin folder, not the projectfolder (if you don't give a full path to `WriteLinesFromListToTextFile( )` since it will use current director, which is where your exe is.

Comment: I also created a folder and put the txt inside and specified it with the path of the folder which is on the project (i do this because this file has to be accessed from many computers and there should not be some hard coded path) but it didnt work too. how can i solve this with a general path that will be good in any pc?

Comment: Side comment: put `StreamWriter writer = ` into `using() {..}` and remove `writer.Close()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unsure of what you are trying to archive, but I understand you this way:

You have a text file as part of you project. At runtime, you try to write some text to this file. When you application is closed, you expect to see the changes in the text file that's part of your project.

Am I right?

If so, I would guess the problem is as follow: When you first start your application, the text file that is part of your project is copied to the output folder together with your executable. The program runs, and the file is manipulated. But when the application closes, files are never copied back from the output folder to the project folder. That's just not how thing works...

Comment: You understood me correctly. The reason i want the file to be in the project is due to the fact that its general and no special path should be specified in any computer. can i fix this if this file will be located in the bin folder or another folder that you reccommend?

Comment: When you release your app, it will make the file in the executable folder, and it will read and write from it there.

Create the textfile in the root of your project, and mark it as 'copy if newer'. This way, your default values will be provided with the first release. After that, the executable will manipulate it as it should. If you during development need to make changes to the file, change it, a the file in your bin folder will be overwritten at your next run.

Development is a special case. When the app is deployed, it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If your program needs access to a file, and you don't specify a path, it uses the current location of the .exe. If this is good enough for your purposes then you just need to know that you can't add it to the solution; like Vegar said, it doesn't work that way. What you CAN do is compile your program, then browse to the folder where the .exe is (debug, release, or other) and run the .exe right from there, then open the text file and review your changes. If you need to create or ensure the file already exists, you can do that in the code as well. You won't be able to include it in your solution but you can still write to the file.